# Safe and generic serialization in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, serialization

I want to (de)serialize simple objects in Python to a human-readable (e.g. JSON) format. The data may come from an untrusted source. I really like how the Rust library, serde, works:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let point = Point { x: 1, y: 2 };

    // Convert the Point to a JSON string.
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&point).unwrap();

    // Prints serialized = {"x":1,"y":2}
    println!("serialized = {}", serialized);

    // Convert the JSON string back to a Point.
    let deserialized: Point = serde_json::from_str(&serialized).unwrap();

    // Prints deserialized = Point { x: 1, y: 2 }
    println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);
}
```

I'd like to achieve something like this in Python. Since Python is not statically typed, I'd expect the syntax to be something like:

```
deserialized = library.loads(data_str, ClassName)
```

where `ClassName` is the expected class.

1. `jsonpickle` is bad, bad, bad. It makes absolutely no sanitization and its usage leads to arbitrary code execution
2. There are the serialization libraries: `lima`, `marshmallow`, `kim` but all of them require manually defining serialization schemes. It, in fact, leads to code duplication, which is bad.

Is there anything I could use for simple, generic yet secure serialization in Python?

EDIT: other requirements, which were implicit before

1. Handle nested serialization (serde can do it: https://gist.github.com/63bcd00691b4bedee781c49435d0d729)
2. Handle built-in types, i.e. be able to serialize and deserialize everything that the built-in `json` module can, without special treatment of built-in types.

Comment: Give an example of how this is expected to work with a builtin type. How would go from say, a json object, to a list?

Comment: For example, `deserialize('[1, 3]', List[int])`? Basically, if a type is given, be able to deserialize anything the built-in `json` module can.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python doesn't require type annotations, any such library would need to either

1. use its own classes
2. take advantage of type annotations.

The latter would be the perfect solution but I have not found any library doing that.

I found a module, though, which requires to define only one class as a model: https://github.com/dimagi/jsonobject

Usage example:

```
import jsonobject


class Node(jsonobject.JsonObject):
    id = jsonobject.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    name = jsonobject.StringProperty(required=True)


class Transaction(jsonobject.JsonObject):
    provider = jsonobject.ObjectProperty(Node)
    requestor = jsonobject.ObjectProperty(Node)


req = Node(id=42, name="REQ")
prov = Node(id=24, name="PROV")

tx = Transaction(provider=prov, requestor=req)
js = tx.to_json()
tx2 = Transaction(js)
print(tx)
print(tx2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python, I would start just by checking the size of the input.  The only security risk is running *json.load()* is a DOS by sending an enormous file.

Once the JSON is parsed, consider running a schema validator such as [PyKwalify](https://pypi.org/project/pykwalify/).